# S3 - All my data appears to be gone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[image]I set up a policy to migrate the data in my bucket to Glacier. That policy has run, but there is nothing in the UI that shows a way to list the assets.

**Management** > **Metrics** shows the number of assets and the storage used, but that drops to zero after the policy ran.

I can see that the Lifecycle ran, but why are the files not listed?

Also, there no Glacier billing in my February invoice, thus far.

How do I list, and potentially store my data, or has it simply been deleted?

Here is the event that ran, according to CloudTrail.

```
{
    "eventVersion": "1.05",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "Root",
        "principalId": "857474361823",
        "arn": "arn:aws:iam::857474361823:root",
        "accountId": "857474361823",
        "accessKeyId": "ASIAIU3ERFRW7WLHUCFQ",
        "sessionContext": {
            "attributes": {
                "mfaAuthenticated": "false",
                "creationDate": "2018-01-24T01:52:51Z"
            }
        }
    },
    "eventTime": "2018-01-24T02:11:13Z",
    "eventSource": "s3.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "PutBucketLifecycle",
    "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "68.226.88.182",
    "userAgent": "[S3Console/0.4, aws-internal/3]",
    "requestParameters": {
        "lifecycle": [
            ""
        ],
        "bucketName": "2011-macbook-pro",
        "LifecycleConfiguration": {
            "Rule": {
                "Status": "Enabled",
                "Filter": {
                    "Prefix": ""
                },
                "Transition": [
                    {
                        "StorageClass": "STANDARD_IA",
                        "Days": 30
                    },
                    {
                        "StorageClass": "GLACIER",
                        "Days": 60
                    }
                ],
                "Expiration": {
                    "Days": 90
                },
                "ID": "Transition to Glacier",
                "AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload": {
                    "DaysAfterInitiation": 7
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "responseElements": null,
    "additionalEventData": {
        "vpcEndpointId": "vpce-6d72a204"
    },
    "requestID": "C432B423C8D99B5E",
    "eventID": "13f42a8a-ad0c-47b8-a0dd-9a617e40f31b",
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "recipientAccountId": "857474361823",
    "vpcEndpointId": "vpce-6d72a204"
}
```

Comment: Can you post your policy?  It does sound like your data has been deleted.

Comment: What policy? Do you mean the Lifecycle rule?

Comment: Even if the data got deleted from the bucket, shouldn't I be able to retrieve it from Glacier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked the service to do the following:

- migrate all objects to the STANDARD_IA storage class as soon as possible but not sooner than 30 days after object creation
- migrate all objects to the GLACIER storage class as soon as possible but not sooner than 60 days after object creation
- delete your objects completely, regardless of storage class, as soon as possible but not sooner than 90 days after object creation

Your objects that were more than 90 days old were deleted.

This...

```
"Expiration": {
      "Days": 90
 },
```

...means you don't want to keep anything, anywhere, if it is over 90 days old.

When an object is transitioned to the GLACIER storage class, it is still logically the same S3 object, but S3 is using Glacier as the backing store for the object payload, rather than using S3's own hard drives.  If you instruct S3 to delete such an object, directly or via lifecycle rules, S3 instructs Glacier to delete the content that Glacier is storing on S3's behalf.  Deleting an object from S3 always means the same thing, regardless of the storage class.